Open .webp image in picturebox (Winforms, C#)
Do you have any suggestions on importing .webp images in pictureboxes without using external libraries? I read on a post here that in theory System.Drawing supports .webp format but found nothing about how to actually use it. I basically need to use wepb images for general purposes like you would use any Image or Bitmap instead of jpeg or png images.

The System.Drawing's support of WebP is, as correctly suggested, theoretical. There are no encoders or decoders that can handle the format (neither internal nor WIC extensions). GDI+ knows that the format exists, there's an ImageType for it, as for HEIF, but that's it... System.Drawing.Common just reflects the GDI+ enumeration
